# Icon inside flexbox container gets stretched on Chrome but not on Firefox

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a navigation menu using `flexbox` to align the elements. The menu will contain both text links and icons, and has this structure:

```
<header>
    <div>Logo</div>
    <nav>
        <ul class="Navigation__nav-menu">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">About</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="Navigation__social-icons-item-link">
                    <img src="icon.png">
                </a>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
```

Here's the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/7brw7s18/1/

The problem is that on Firefox the icon respect the width of the parent element and the height is set accordingly. On Chrome it gets stretched vertically.
Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think your problem is the 'display flex' in the anchor, try to remove it as follows:

```
.Navigation__social-icons-item-link {
    //display:flex
}
```

And here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7brw7s18/2/)